# How can I get a list from min() method in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to learn pygame and python by making some simple clicking games and the following program I made draws a grid and when I click on any box in the grid, it changes it's colour. But that's limited to one box per click.

What I'm trying to do is to colour clicked box and all the other box with similar x coordinates or y coordinates, x and y coordinates meaning `<rect(x, y, 70, 90)>` x-y in a pygame.Rect

Here's my code with all the relevant functions in question.

```
import pygame as pg
import sys

window_width = 720
window_height = 360
window_res = window_width, window_height

cover_width = 70
cover_height = 90

gap_x = 70
gap_y = 90

red = (225, 25, 30)
bkg_colour = (30, 30, 30)
off_white = (180, 180, 180)
magenta = (225, 25, 25)


def get_rekt():
    init_x = int((window_width % gap_x) / 2)
    init_y = 20

    rect_list = []
    for x in range(init_x, window_width - gap_x, gap_x):
        for y in range(init_y, window_height - gap_y, gap_y):
            rect = pg.Rect(x, y, cover_width, cover_height)
            rect_list.append(rect)

    return rect_list


def draw_grid(rect_list):
    for rect in rect_list:
        pg.draw.rect(display, red, rect, 3)


def get_grid():
    return draw_grid(get_rekt())


def get_closest_rect(rect_list, click_pos):
    closest_rect = min(rect_list, key=lambda x: abs(x.centerx - click_pos[0]) + abs(x.centery - click_pos[1]))
    return closest_rect


def main():
    pg.init()

    global display, fps_clock

    display = pg.display.set_mode(window_res)
    display.fill(bkg_colour)
    draw_grid(get_rekt())
    pg.display.flip()

    while True:

        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                click_pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
                rect_list = get_rekt()
                closest_rect = get_closest_rect(rect_list, click_pos)
                pg.draw.rect(display, off_white, closest_rect, 3)
                pg.display.flip()
                print(closest_rect)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the function that returns closest rect to where I clicked. I'm using min() method with lambda key.

```
def get_closest_rect(rect_list, click_pos):
    closest_rect = min(rect_list, key=lambda x: abs(x.centerx - click_pos[0]) + abs(x.centery - click_pos[1]))
    return closest_rect
```

This is what it looks like when I click in a box

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssOj1.png)

And what I'm looking for is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8WAE.png)

What I was thinking is if this function

```
def get_closest_rect(rect_list, click_pos):
        closest_rect = min(rect_list, key=lambda x: abs(x.centerx - click_pos[0]) + abs(x.centery - click_pos[1]))
        return closest_rect
```

could return a list of rect with similar x or y coordinates, I could run that list in a for loop with pg.draw and do what you can see in the second image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should do the trick.

```
def get_closest_rects(rect_list, click_pos):
  return filter(lambda r: r.left <= click_pos[0] <= r.right or r.top <= click_pos[1] <= r.bottom, rect_list)
```

`filter(function, iterable)` returns a list of elements from *iterable* for which *function* returns `True`.

To get the rectangles above and below the cursor, we just have to check if the cursor is between the left and right boundaries of each rectangle. For those left and right, we have to check the top and bottom boundaries.

If you replace the boolean `or` operation with an `and`, you'll only get the one rectangle you've clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use it:

```
            if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            click_pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            rect_list = get_rekt()
            closest_rect = get_closest_rect(rect_list, click_pos)
            linex = 10
            liney = 20
            for i in range(0,10):#x axis
                newRect=pg.Rect(linex, closest_rect.y, cover_width, cover_height)
                pg.draw.rect(display, off_white, newRect, 3)
                linex = linex + 70

            for j in range(0,3):
                newRect = pg.Rect(closest_rect.x, liney, cover_width, cover_height)
                pg.draw.rect(display, off_white, newRect, 3)
                liney = liney + 90

            pg.display.flip()
```